# angularjs conditional syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

I have a [$parse:syntax] error with this code :

```
<img class="trs_img" id="{{ 'TRS_EN' | translate, 'active' : menu == 'lord'}}" ng-click="changeLanguage('en');" />
```

- first : translation id translated with angular-translate,
- second: id active if it's check the value 'lord' in menu scope

what is the good syntax?

Comment: @RajavelD I don't know how that suggestion passed, but that list has no place in a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double curly braces:

```
<img class="trs_img" id="{'TRS_EN' | translate, 'active' : menu == 'lord'}" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two IDs in one element - if you want something like this try use `ng-class`.